# Multiple Leaflet maps on web site in different divs

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, leaflet

I'm pretty new to leaflet.js and I'm trying to figure out how to assign the same map with the same set of options and layers to a different HTML container instead of having to remove and add a new one every time?

I used to deal with OpenLayers 2 and I had `map.render(div);` option every time I wanted to set map to another div.

Is there solution to this?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, did you get any further with this? I'm into a similar problem and curious to compare notes. FWIW I am able to 1) get the html contents of the `.leaflet-map-pane` class, 2) open a new window, 3) instantiate a new Leaflet map in a fresh `div` in my new window, then 4) use JQuery to intrusively change the html value of the `.leaflet-map-pane` class in the new window/div. It works, but the map is essentially "soulless", unable to drag, etc. Curious if you ended up with something better.

Comment: Hi, @elrobis. Sorry for the delay. To solve this - I ended up destroying map every time I had to create the new one. I was able to run multiple maps at once - not a big deal, but I once I reached 8-10 maps my ionic app started crashing. 
I now use Angular and its Leaflet directive Angular-leaflet-directive. It does initialization and management under the hood and all you need to do is to pass some initial parameters.